# Restart activity from back hard key in context menu

Tags: android, android-intent, listener, back

I want to check to see if the hard back key on the device is pressed within my context menu only so I can run an intent to restart the activity. Thanks. Heres my code so far

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    item = menu.add("Something");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_something);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //search
    if (item.getTitle() == "Something") {
//how do I check if hard back key was pressed inside this IF statement as to run below intent
        Intent myCustomView = new Intent(this, com.example.something.class);
        startActivityForResult(myCustomView, RESULT_OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I load the gun for you, it's generally discouraged to alter the function of the hardware keys. Users expect certain behaviors, and they shouldn't be messed with.

That said, you can do it bay catching the onKeyDown event and testing to see if the Back key is the one that was pressed:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do your thing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: On re-reading your question, I now realize that it sounds like you're wanting to detect a press while a context menu is displayed. I don't know if/how that can be done, but I hope the above is still helpful.

Comment: that code won't run inside the IF statement and outside it changes back to effect whole activity. I only want back to be effected inside that IF statement

Comment: So the user brings up the menu, presses the back key (which does not close the menu), the program simply notes that the button was pressed, the user selects the "Something" item, and the program handles the "Something" selection in a special way because the Back Key has been pressed. Is that correct?

Comment: in   if (item.getTitle() == "Something") { } I have a multi selection radio box and ten user picks certain items and when they hit back I want to restart the activity because all the content will change. Do you follow? I don't even no if this is the right way of going about this

Comment: I solved this by simply adding a positiveButton to the dialog. thanks for help